# boost query issue in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

We have below 4 documents under one type and one index. And I queried as below. But the result I got I think it is not correct. Who can help me out? How is the rank works? How does boost impact the score result?

```
{
"title":"title",
"content":"content"
},
{
"title":"title test",
"content":"content"
},
{
"title":"title",
"content":"content test"
},
{
"title":"title test",
"content":"content test"
}
```

While I queried below:

```
{
  "query": {  
    "bool": {  
      "should": [
                { "match": {
                    "title": {
                        "query": "test",
                        "boost": 3
                    }
                }},
                { "match": {
                    "content": {
                        "query": "test",
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }}
            ] 
    }
  }
  }
```

I got the below result.

```
{
    "took": 10,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 3,
        "successful": 3,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 3,
        "max_score": 2.4428198,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "bt",
                "_type": "blog",
                "_id": "m4w7_GIB24WOZoUoiMIP",
                "_score": 2.4428198,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "title test",
                    "content": "content"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "bt",
                "_type": "blog",
                "_id": "nYw7_GIB24WOZoUoiMIP",
                "_score": 1.1507283,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "title test",
                    "content": "content test"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "bt",
                "_type": "blog",
                "_id": "nIw7_GIB24WOZoUoiMIP",
                "_score": 0.8142733,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "title",
                    "content": "content test"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My Question is why I can't get the first one as 2 tests. The result is the first one as test in title?